# PayPal payments queue

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/) documentation PayPal says:

> PayPal automatically queues payments based on the billing start date, billing frequency, and billing amount.

So if at 8 AM today PayPal will charge my customer's account, can I as a developer receive that information and check whether my product for that recurring bill is expired then cancel this subscription before 8 AM today? (like right before PayPal charge my customer's account?)

Or I have to run a cronjob for every hour to check product expiration and manually cancel subscription?

Answer (score 0):

That document is an old and deprecated recurring payments integration method.

If you use the current [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), you can register for [webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions).